# How can I list last 5 days result in mongodb database?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to list last 5 days result by writing mongodb queries.

```
    Date.prototype.addDays = function(h) {    
   this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h*60*60*1000*24)); 
   return this;   
} 

var beforeDate = (new Date()).addDays(-5);

var result = db.xxx.find( { CreatedDate: { $lt: beforeDate } } )
        .map(function (doc) { return doc._id; });


    print("----");
    print(result);
```

but result is not meaningful. How can I list my data in mongodb collection in last 5 days writing simple query.

```
Script executed successfully, an empty result returned.
// Command #3 8:1 0,387 s
Script executed successfully, an empty result returned.
// Command #4 12:5 0,001 s
----
// Command #5 13:5 0,003 s
BinData(3,"FJguxz9zEk6e+is8JKRJGw=="),BinData(3, . . . . . ."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this sample data,

```
/* 1 createdAt:26/07/2019, 15:53:51*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3ad4b7a8672903e950a0c2"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-07-19T13:55:09.000+05:30")
},

/* 2 createdAt:26/07/2019, 15:53:47*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3ad4b3a8672903e950a0c1"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-07-20T13:55:09.000+05:30")
},

/* 3 createdAt:26/07/2019, 15:53:44*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3ad4b0a8672903e950a0c0"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-07-21T13:55:09.000+05:30")
},

/* 4 createdAt:26/07/2019, 15:53:41*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3ad4ada8672903e950a0bf"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-07-22T13:55:09.000+05:30")
},

/* 5 createdAt:26/07/2019, 15:53:36*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3ad4a8a8672903e950a0be"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-07-23T13:55:09.000+05:30")
},

/* 6 createdAt:26/07/2019, 15:53:34*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3ad4a6a8672903e950a0bd"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-07-24T13:55:09.000+05:30")
},

/* 7 createdAt:26/07/2019, 15:53:30*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3ad4a2a8672903e950a0bc"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-07-25T13:55:09.000+05:30")
},

/* 8 createdAt:26/07/2019, 15:53:26*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3ad49ea8672903e950a0bb"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-07-26T13:55:09.000+05:30")
}
```

You need to make the query,

```
db.drt.find({ date: { $lt: date } }).limit(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

For last 5 days data you should have query like:

```
db.drt.find({ date: { $gt:  new Date("2019-07-21T11:44:16.082Z") } })
```

And the javascript logic would be as below:

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(h) {    
   this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h*60*60*1000*24)); 
   return this.toISOString();   
} 

var beforeDate = (new Date()).addDays(-5);

console.log(beforeDate);
```

> Note: Don't use `limit`. It will give you only 5 records where we need last 5 days records that can be possible multiples.

Hope this help!